default pnotify notification on page load
I recently install pnotify on my project and when i add css and js files it shows following notification on every page load on every page. I try to remove it using different scripts but cant

I want to remove this notification which shows on every page load. thanks in advance

Check https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/312
